# how to update twitter timeline with jsoup

Tags: java, twitter, web-scraping

I do not know how to update twitter timeline with jsoup. Can anyone help me?

timeline updates itself every few second, I have this code to retrieve current timeline but how to update it every few second.

```
void searchTweet() throws IOException {
    List<Tweets> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();
    Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com").userAgent(userAgent).cookies(cookies).execute();
    Element streamTag = response.parse().getElementById("stream-items-id");
    String id;
    String tweet_stat_count;
    Elements li = streamTag.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-item-type", "tweet");

    for (Element elementOfLiTag : li) {
        Elements span = elementOfLiTag.select("span.ProfileTweet-actionCount");
        id = elementOfLiTag.attr("data-item-id");
        tweet_stat_count = span.get(1).attr("data-tweet-stat-count");
        String text = elementOfLiTag.getElementsByClass("TweetTextSize").text();

    }
}
```

[firebug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9QMr.png)

Comment: [link]((https://twitter.com/i/timeline?composed_count=0&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&include_new_items_bar=true&interval=10000&latent_count=0&min_position=775888754129063937) 
They use get method I want to simulate any ideas?

Comment: So you want to call this method every few seconds, is that it?

Comment: @JoeC Yes but it is dynamic here is the fields
composed_count 0
include_available_feature... 1
include_entities 1
include_new_items_bar  true
interval 10000
latent_count 0
min_position  775888754129063937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a task every few seconds, you can use a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.schedule(this::searchTweet, 5, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```